# get httppost response like when using inspect element in chrome using java

Tags: android, asp.net, http-post, jsoup

I'm sending an httppost request to a web site (asp) and I'm trying to find a table in the HTML source by using EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8") but I can't find the table that I'm looking for.

BUT, when I'm clicking on inspect element in chrome for the same web page I can see a whole new world which contains my table and a lot more.

Is there a way to get the same raw data as in Chrome's inspect element in an android app?

Comment: Could you provide the url? It sounds like the table is generated by javascript. If you don't know that already, javascript is executed on the client (the browser), if you do know that, don't mind me. If that's the case, then Jsoup can't help you. Jsoup can only parse the html that is generated on the server. Press Ctrl+U while on the page with chrome. If the table is there, then update your question with that html, if you don't, then you have to find some other way (search for "headless browser", "selenium for android" etc)

Comment: this is the URL [link](http://www.cibus.co.il/rest.aspx?PassTrue=0) you should click on the left grey square and see the table below

Answer (score 0):

- Chrome handles cookie and session management automatically, along with typical connection management aspects (eg: cache, keep alive, etc)
- Make sure your android app is making the http post request with all the necessary headers, cookie/session, and input parameters.
- You can use [chrome dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) to capture and see the full request/response detials. See if its sending any cookie information to the server. If so, you will need to modify your android app to do the same.

Comment: also in Chrome when I'm clicking view source I can't see the table in the html code but only when I'm clicking Inspect Element